# Neon Animated Pages not within Paper Material

Tags: html, css, polymer-1.0

My Neon Animated Pages will not display inside my Paper Material.

Here you can see in my bare-bones example that my neon animated pages will not display inside the paper material. The Paper Material is outlined by a red border. In theory the paper material should have a bottom border and borders along the right and left side that also encompass the blue div. My best guess is that it is a CSS rule in the neon-animated-pages element itself that is overriding the correct behavior. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance. 
[image: Example]

Code for bare-bones exapmle:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animation.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animated-pages.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/neon-shared-element-animatable-behavior.html">

        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html" >
        <style>
        </style>

    </head>

    <body fullbleed unresolved vertical>
        <test-iron-page></test-iron-page>
    </body>

<dom-module id="test-iron-page">
    <style is="custom-style">


        p {
            font-size: 5em;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        paper-material {
            margin: 0px;
            border: 1px red solid;
        }

        .bigDiv {
            background: rgb(0, 148, 255);
            height: 150px;
        }

        .smallDiv {
            background: rgb(0, 255, 144);
            height: 40px;
        }
    </style>

    <template>

        <paper-material elevation="2">

            <div id="headerCont">
                <p>Header</p>
            </div>
            <neon-animated-pages id="nap" selected="0">
                <div class="bigDiv">I am a div</div>
                <div class="smallDiv">I am a div</div>
            </neon-animated-pages>

        </paper-material>

    </template>

</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "test-iron-page"
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Give a height to the paper-material

Answer (score 1):

Specify the `height` of the `paper-material`, Here is the working demo with `height:300px;` for `paper-material`.

```html
<html>  
<head>

  <title>Template me</title>
  
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/webcomponents.js"></script>
  
  <base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.0.1/lib/">
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">  
  <link rel="import" href="neon-animation/neon-animation.html">
        <link rel="import" href="neon-animation/neon-animated-pages.html">
        <link rel="import" href="neon-animation/neon-shared-element-animatable-behavior.html">

        <link rel="import" href="paper-material/paper-material.html" >
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html" >
  
</head>
    <body fullbleed unresolved vertical>
        <test-iron-page></test-iron-page>
    </body>

<dom-module id="test-iron-page">
    <style is="custom-style">


        p {
            font-size: 5em;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        paper-material {
            margin: 0px;
            border: 1px red solid;
            height : 300px;
        }

        .bigDiv {
            background: rgb(0, 148, 255);
            height: 150px;
        }

        .smallDiv {
            background: rgb(0, 255, 144);
            height: 40px;
        }
    </style>

    <template>

        <paper-material elevation="2">

            <div id="headerCont">
                <p>Header</p>
            </div>
            <neon-animated-pages id="nap" selected="0">
                <div class="bigDiv">I am a div</div>
                <div class="smallDiv">I am a div</div>
            </neon-animated-pages>
            
        </paper-material>
<paper-button raised on-tap="_next">Next Page</paper-button>
    </template>

</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "test-iron-page",
        _next : function(){
          this.$.nap.selected = ((this.$.nap.selected+1)%2);
        }
    });
</script>

</html>
```